# Socket chat room in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, tcp, chat

This is a Python chat room that I've been working on and it enables to you to chat to other people on the same network through Python.

## Server.py:

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
print(" server will start on host : ", host)
port = 8080
s.bind((host,port))
name = input(str("Please enter your username: "))
print("")
print("Server is waiting for incoming connections")
print("")
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Recieved connection")
print("")
s_name = conn.recv(1024)
s_name = s_name.decode()
print(s_name, "has joined the chat room")
conn.send(name.encode())

while 1:
    message = input(str("Please enter your message: "))
    conn.send(message.encode())
    print("Sent")
    print("")
    message = conn.recv(1024)
    message = message.decode()
    print(s_name, ":" ,message)
    print("")
```

## Client.py:

```
import socket
import sys

s = socket.socket()
host = input(str("Please enter the hostname of the server : "))
port = 8080
s.connect((host,port))
name = input(str("Please enter your username : "))
print(" Connected to chat server")

s.send(name.encode())
s_name = s.recv(1024)
s_name = s_name.decode()
print("")
print(s_name, "has joined the chat room ")

while 1:
    message = s.recv(1024)
    message = message.decode()
    print(s_name, ":" ,message)
    print("")
    message = input(str("Please enter your message: "))
    message = message.encode()
    s.send(message)
    print("Sent")
    print("")
```

I just wanted suggestions on how I can to improve this chatroom to make it better and faster. All suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
host = input(str("Please enter the hostname of the server : "))
...
message = input(str("Please enter your message: "))
```

can be changed to simply:

```
message = input("Please enter your message: ")
...
host = input("Please enter the hostname of the server : ")
```

since there is no need to cast a string to a string.

```
while 1:
```

is fine, but is more readable as:

```
while True:
```

Having print statements like the following:

```
print("")
```

is redundant. If you want an extra newline after a print statement; Add "\n" to the end of the preceding print statements to remove a function call, and reduce code clutter. E.G:

```
print("Sent\n")
```

This is more of a personal preference, but fstring formatting is more readable  than the following:

```
print(s_name, ":" ,message)
```

should be:

```
print( f"{s_name}: {message}" )
```

Answer (score -2):

If we send two or more messages from any side at once, another side will receive only a single message at once rather than all.